# Ajax syntax not returning all records

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax code snippet that returns a record from the database, that has the same company name as the user inserted in a form.

However the code is returning only one record. Let's say i have 3 records with a company name 'A'.

The code will return only the latest record of these 3, and not all of them.

an alert for 'key' shows that i'm getting all the records inside:

```
 success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('record').each(function() {
            key = $(this).find("KEY").text();
        });
```

however an alert for key outside success shows that i have the last record inserted.

How can i solve this to return all the records that hold the name input by the user?

```
var key = null;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "GetRecord?DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY",
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: {
        "Where": "COMPANY='" + companies_name + "'"   
    },
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('record').each(function() {
            key = $(this).find("KEY").text();
        });

        if (key) {
            var url = "GetDisplay?Template=Record/test.htm&DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY&Where=KEY=" + key + "";
            window.open(url, "_self");
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Not saying I'm right about this, but that looks possibly very insecure to me.

Comment: what is your `xml` data return

Comment: @Roope no you're right, but i'm just trying something

Comment: You are setting `key` to the last one record's value. And anyway, calling `window.open()` from none direct user interaction event is a no go

Comment: I agree with Roope.  You should never give query params in a url.  Your just asking to be sql injected.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi the xml being returned is for all the correct records

Comment: @A.Wolff how can i alter that to get the desired outcome?

Comment: @mikeb So firstly define key locally to `each` loop callback function AND set your logic using it inside loop, not outside. Or use an array to push all relevant keys

Comment: @A.Wolff dear putting the url inside the each function and doing alert to the url shows that i'm getting all the records correctly, but i'm displaying the last record..What more adjustment should i do?

Comment: What do you mean by `i'm displaying the last record`? If you refer to only one `window` is opened, then surely your browser block any other one. That's how modern browsers handle it, blocking unexpected popup.

Comment: @A.Wolff i'm trying to display all the records in the same window